# tomcat is not getting started

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7, liferay-6

I am new to Liferay. I just downloaded the LifeRay (liferay-portal-tomcat-6.2-ce-ga6-20160112152609836.zip) . I extracted it into my C drive in liferay-portal-6.2-ce-ga6 folder.

When I run **c:\liferay-portal-6.2-ce-ga6\tomcat-7.0.62\bin\startup.bat** file it shows the below errors.

```
Using CATALINA_BASE: "C:\liferay-portal-6.2-ce-ga6\tomcat-7.0.62"
Using CATALINA_HOME: "C:\liferay-portal-6.2-ce-ga6\tomcat-7.0.62"
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: "C:\liferay-portal-6.2-ce-ga6\tomcat-7.0.62\temp"
Using JRE_HOME: "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_77"
Using CLASSPATH: "C:\liferay-portal-6.2-ce-ga6\tomcat-7.0.62\bin\bootstrap.jar;C:\liferay-portal-6.2-ce-ga6\tomcat-7.0.62\bin\tomcat-juli.jar"
```

The system cannot find the file specified.

I have checked and both the jars bootstrap.jar and tomcat-juli.jar are present in the tomcat-7.0.62\bin folder.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the error is not referring to the .jar files. The startup.bat is initiating commands line by line, and it got stopped one step after the line with the CLASSPATH.

Could you please post the results of this command:

```
catalina.bat configtest
```

(You can run the command from the command line, from your C:\liferay-portal-6.2-ce-ga6\tomcat-7.0.62\bin folder)

Otherwise, I would suggest to check the followings:

1. try with another bundle
   (https://sourceforge.net/projects/lportal/files/Liferay%20Portal/6.2.4%20GA5/liferay-portal-jboss-6.2-ce-ga5-20151130140127468.zip/download)
2. try with another jdk installed (jdk7)
3. check if the environment variables JAVA_HOME and JRE_HOME were set up correctly
4. verify folder permissions
5. try to start a plain tomcat 7 (without Liferay)
   (https://tomcat.apache.org/download-70.cgi)

I hope you will find these suggestions useful :)

I have just downloaded ga6 now and it started ok for me (Windows7 + jdk7)